# "Vitória seguida". Quantidade e uso correto

Tags: gramática

Hoje pela manhã, li a seguinte frase:

> O Tigre venceu mais uma partida nesta Série B. A vitória sobre o
>   Paysandu por 1 a 0 foi a **segunda seguida** na competição.

Fiquei com uma dúvida.

O time vinha de um empate e uma vitória, e ganhou outro jogo.

**A minha pergunta não é sobre como isso é usado**, pois sempre ouvi frases assim e sei que esta é a maneira que as pessoas, pelo menos habitualmente, se expressam.

Gostaria de saber:

**Isso está correto? Não deveria ser a "primeira vitória seguida", já que é a primeira vitória seguida de outra?**

Eu entendo o que foi dito, mas confesso que quando li fiquei em dúvida se isso é gramaticalmente correto ou se sempre foi usado incorretamente e ficou "normal" falar-se assim.

*Ps.: Perdoem os erros de acentuação e português, e por favor gostaria que corrigissem todos, já que o teclado está em inglês e há muito tempo não convivo com a língua portuguesa diariamente.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, a frase é indiscutivelmente amplamente usada e aceite por toda a gente; por conseguinte, é "correta" sob todas as definições. A questão que resta é como explicá-la.

Um dos significados de "seguido" (como adjetivo), segundo o [Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/seguido):

> 1. Que ocorre num determinado período de tempo, sem intervalo; CONTÍNUO: *Falou duas horas seguidas ao telefone.*

Isto explica "duas vitórias seguidas"; de facto, "a segunda vitória seguida" já parece mais difícil.

Mas repara no exemplo: em "falou duas horas seguidas", não estará "seguidas" a qualificar mais a forma como se falou (ininterruptamente) do que a qualificar as duas horas? Poderíamos reescrever a frase destas formas:

> Falou duas horas de seguida.
>   Falou seguidamente durante duas horas.

Parece-me que o adjetivo "seguidas" tem, quer na tua frase, quer no exemplo do Aulete, uma função essencialmente adverbial. Aliás, o Aulete também lista "seguido" como advérbio:

> 4. Seguidamente, continuamente: *"Contar seguido, alinhavado, só mesmo sendo as coisas de rasa importância."*

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (pág. 1404) descreve a leitura adverbial dos ajetivos desta forma:

> Os adjetivos de leitura adverbial [...] exprimem propriedades relacionadas com as circunstâncias em que decorrem os eventos [...], em particular, a sua duração, a sua localização temporal, o modo como os participantes neles envolvidos atuam e a maneira como se articula a sua estrutura temporal interna — aquilo a que se chama o aspeto: se são pontuais ou durativos, se se articulam em momentos internos distintos (chamados “fases”), se se repetem, e com que periocidade. Dadas as características, os nomes com que estes adjetivos se combinan [...] são, de forma geral, nomes eventivos — i.e., que denotam eventos.

E mais adiante (pág. 1412):

> Os adjetivos aspetuais denotam a maneira como uma situação se processa ou se desenvolve no tempo, exprimindo em particular repetição (ou iteração) de eventos e a continuidade prolongada de um estado. Constituem exemplos *cíclico*, *constante*, *continuado*, *contínuo*, *esporádico*, *frequente*, *habitual*, *ocasional*, *permanente*, *pontual*, *regular*, *repetido*, *seguido*.

Portanto, a melhor forma de ler "seguida" em "foi a segunda vitória seguida na competição" é adverbialmente. Quando passamos de "foi a segunda vitória" para "foi a segunda vitória seguida", vemos que "seguida" não está a qualificar a vitória (da forma que outros adjetivos como "curta", "larga", "convincente", etc.), mas a forma como as vitórias aconteceram (de seguida/seguidamente).

Answer (score 7):

Eu compreendo que, se estivéssemos agora a inventar a língua, se pudesse chamar a *primeira vitória seguida* à segunda de duas vitórias sem empates ou derrotas pelo meio. Mas chamar-lhe *segunda vitória seguida* também é perfeitamente natural. Não me parece que haja maneira de escolhermos entre as duas apenas por lógica. Logo o significado correto é definido pelo uso. Portanto o meu veredicto é que *segunda vitória seguida* é que é correto. Também é este o uso em Portugal.

Se estivesse a redigir algo com implicações legais, pelo seguro, podia escrever:

> Com a vitória sobre o Paysandu por 1 a 0 o Tigre tem agora duas vitórias seguidas.

Ou consecutivas. Seria disparatado argumentar-se que não, que só tinha uma seguida.

Comment: Voce tem alguma fonte de origem, mostrando como isso surgiu, se foi usado errado e ficou como certo, ou se foi criado assim?

Comment: @guisasso Recorri apenas à lógica e uso. Se quiséssemos ser ultrarrigorosos, a vitória anterior é a primeira vitória seguida, porque foi seguida pela pela vitória no jogo seguinte; esta última só se poderia chamar segunda vitória seguida se o time ganhasse também o jogo seguinte (passando a ter três vitórias seguidas).

Comment: @guisasso  De acordo com os dicionários, duas vitórias sem empates ou derrotas pelo meio são duas vitórias seguidas. _Primeira seguida_ ou _segunda seguida_ não encontrei em dicionário nenhum. Mas faz perfeito sentido, por extensão do significado de _duas vitórias seguidas_, chamar à segunda destas vitórias a _segunda seguida_. Parece-me que é isto que justifica o uso corrente.

Comment: Interessante. Voce sabe se alguma coutra palavra ficaria mais correto, ou, daria a entender no sentido em que falo e nao no sentido em que fiquei em duvida, como sendo somente a primeira seguida de outra? Por exemplo, no ingles se fala "in a row". Em sequencia, consecutiva.. ?

Comment: _Consecutiva_ parece-me um sinónimo de _seguida_. Podemos dizer _a segunda de duas vitórias seguidas_: houve duas vitórias seguidas, e nós estamos a falar da segunda delas. Ou talvez _a segunda vitória de enfiada_. Algumas pessoas poderão achar esta última muito informal.

Answer (score 6):

Gramaticalmente está correto, e o objetivo é diferenciar uma segunda vitória **com derrotas ou empates entre elas**, de uma segunda vitória **sem nenhum jogo entre elas**.  Tendo lógica ou não, é assim que se diz. (no Brasil)

Comment: Completando. Elas são seguidas, pois elas se seguem, são sucessivas. "foi a segunda vitória seguida" -> foi sucessivamente a segunda vitória

Answer (score 2):

Sim, essa frase gramaticalmente está correta. Dependendo do jeito que a frase é interpretada, pode parecer estranho ou não.

Primeiramente, tem-se que ter em mente que o assunto principal do texto é que "*o Tigre venceu mais uma partida*". Ou seja, o contexto é que o Tigre teve uma vitória além de outra que teve anteriormente.

Depois é explicado que "*a vitória [...] foi a segunda seguida*". Agora sabe-se que ocorreram duas vitórias, e que essa última foi seguida, isto é, saiu vitorioso **duas vezes seguidas**.

A paráfrase dessa frase ficaria como:

> A vitória sobre o Paysandu por 1 a 0 foi a **segunda vitória, na qual essa foi seguida da primeira** na competição.

O que aconteceu nessa frase foi a omissão dos detalhes, que a deixou com apenas "segunda seguida", mas que apesar de poder parecer estranho ou incorreto, tem o mesmo sentido de "duas vezes seguidas".

Answer (score 0):

A frase que você citou está gramaticalmente correta, porém logicamente errada. O seu raciocínio correto. Para estar gramaticalmente e logicamente correta a frase deveria ser reformulada para "o Tigre venceu o Paysandu por 1 a 0 e chega a duas vitórias seguidas". Note que "vitórias seguidas" é uma coisa (foram duas vitórias e uma foi seguida da outra); outra coisa é "segunda vitória seguida" (para ter a segunda vitória seguida é necessário ter havido a primeira vitória seguida).

Answer (score 0):

Vejamos.

Se eu pergunto, "quantas vitórias a Ponte Preta obteve no campeonato brasileiro?", e me respondem, "quatorze, sendo seis seguidas", devo entender que a Ponte Preta obteve uma série ininterrupta de seis vitórias... ou uma série ininterrupta de sete vitórias?

A mim me parece que a primeira interpretação é a intuitiva. "Seis vitórias seguidas" significa uma série de seis vitórias, não de sete.

Agora, por que a interpretação mudaria se substituo o numeral cardinal por um numeral ordinal? Para mim, se "seis vitórias seguidas" significa uma série de seis vitórias, por que "a sexta vitória seguida" seria a sétima de uma série de sete, em vez da sexta de uma série de seis?